# Making a module work like an intrinsic Fortran module

Tags: module, fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

I have a module `module1` in a file called `mymodule.f90`. What should I do in order to make `module1` usable like fortran intrinsic module?, i.e. it need only be called in a use statement (`use module1`) in any programs, subroutines, or functions that use it but I don't need to link `/path/to/mymodule/` when compiling those procedures.

I use gfortran, but possibly in the future I will also have to use the Intel fortran compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compile `mymodule.f90` you will obtain an object file (`mymodule.o`) and a module file (`mymodule1.mod`).  The compiler needs to have access to the module file when it compiles other files that `use mymodule1`, and the linker needs to have access to the object file when it generates the binary.

You don't need to specify the location of intrinsic modules because they are built in into the compiler. That will not be the case with your modules: you may be able to set up your environment in a way that the locations of your files allow the compiler to find the files without explicitly specifying their paths in compilation or linking commands, but the fact that you don't see it does not mean it's not happening.

For the Intel compiler, the answer is given by https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/694273 :

> Directories are searched for .mod files in this order:
>
> 1 Directory of the source file that contains the USE statement.
>
> 2 Directories specified by the module path compiler option.
>
> 3 Current working directory.
>
> 4 Directories specified by the -Idir (Linux* and OS X*) or /include (Windows*) option.
>
> 5 Directories specified with the CPATH or INCLUDE environment variable.
>
> 6 Standard system directories.

For gfortran I have not found such a clear ordered list, but relevant information can be found in

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Directory-Options.html

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options

It should be clear to you that a compiler won't be able to understand module files created by other compilers, or even by different enough versions of the same compiler.  Therefore, you would need a copy of your "always available" module for each compiler you use, and if you are using multiple versions of a compiler you may need up to one per version - each of them in a different directory to avoid errors.

As you can see, this is not particularly practical, and it is indeed far from common practice.  It is usually easier and more clear to the user to specify the path to the relevant module file in the compilation command.  This is quite easy to set up if you compile your code using tools such as make.

Finally, remember that, if you make such arrangements for module files, you will also need to make arrangements for the corresponding object files at the linking stage.

Answer (score 3):

So maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but you want to use a module without having to tell the compiler where to find the .mod file (that contains the interface definitions for whatever `module1` exports), or the linker where the object code can be found?

If so, for GFortran the solution is to download the GCC source code, add your own module as an intrinsic module, and then build your own custom version of GFortran. As a word of warning, unless you're familiar with the GFortran/GCC internals, while this isn't rocket science, it isn't trivial either.

For Intel Fortran, where you presumably don't have access to the source code of the compiler, I suppose you're out of luck.

My suggestion is to forget about this, and instead tell the compiler/linker where your .mod files and object files can be found.  There are tools like make, cmake etc. that can help you automate this.